# Is there no method called when using [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Tags: xcode4.2

As the title says: Is there no method being called on my other ViewController when I'm dismissing my modal view to return to it? (Apparently viewDidAppear didn't do it, perhaps because I use the Partial Curl transition?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not get notified in any standard way. In some cases `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` might get triggered but you really shouldn't rely on it.

Implement a delegate that tells you when the view is dismissed.

Comment: Hmm, and how would I go about and achieve that? :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c